# Extracting string from filename after removing Date from the string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a requirement where depending on the filename I am required to call different methods 
filename example are as below

- Abc_def_20180719_ghi.txt
- Pqr_xy_gh_20180730.txt

Here I want to remove all the characters once I encounter datepattern 
So the output should be like:

- "Abc_def"
- "Pqr_xy_gh"

Please suggest suitable string operations with regex

Comment: Sooo, the names won't container any other numbers other then the date?

Comment: They can contain but numbers would be after the date string only ex abc_def_20180719_1200.txt.   to indicate time

Comment: The question is unclear, because it seems so confusingly simple. Read it as it is, it sounds like "How to delete the sequence of digits, the preceding underscore and anything afterwards?" Please demonstrate your level of understanding regex by showing something which gets as close as you can to the goal. Also please explain more about the rules. Can there be other digits which needs to stay? What are the trickiest inputs you can think of. What did you try and what is wrong about its results?

Comment: I might start with `[0-9]{8}`, which will match the date values, and see where it takes you

Comment: Yes precisely what you thought is right ,you can put it that way deleting digits from the string and everything afterwards,the numbers in the string mainly indicate date and time which will be dynamic for a filename and what remains constant is the string that comes before these digits and need to extract that

Comment: Maybe this is the regex you are looking for: `^([\w\_]*.[\_\w]*)\.xml$`, I am new to regex so this is the best I can think of.

Comment: You can use this regex for extracting the required substring. ([a-zA-Z_]+)(?=_[0-9]{8}). Substring would be present in the first capturing group of regex. See here https://regex101.com/r/bm7JpW/1 for demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filtering all numbers you can use: `yourText.replaceAll("[0-9]","")` .
But if you want to drop the .txt use: `yourTextAfterReplacingAll.split("\\.")`

The text you want is in `yourTextAfterSplit[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex to detect required portion of file name

```
/.+(?=_\d{8})/
```

For demonstration have a look [here](https://regexr.com/3snut). It detects any character except line breaks before an underscore and concurrent 8 digits which is pattern of date.

Answer (score 0):

It may be overthinking it a little to validate that the date at least superficially looks like a good date. This regex could be simplified if you don't care about invalid dates like 10664964.

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DatePrefix {
    // no digits before date; year must be between 2000 and 9999
    // month from 01 to 12, day from 01 to 31
    private static Pattern beforeDate = Pattern.compile(
        "([^0-9]+)_[2-9]\\d{3}(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:0[1-9]|[1-2]\\d|3[01])");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String filename : args) {
            getPrefixBeforeDate(filename)
                .ifPresentOrElse(
                        prefix -> System.out.format("Found %s%n", prefix),
                        () -> System.out.format("Bad date: %s%n", filename));
        }
    }

    public static Optional<String> getPrefixBeforeDate(String filename) {
        Matcher matcher = beforeDate.matcher(filename);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return Optional.of(matcher.group(1));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

When called with:

```
java DatePrefix Pq_xy_20180229.txt Abc_def_ghi_20380323_foo_1200.xml \
Hey_its_20182395.gif Foo_bar.txt
```

It prints:

```
Found Pq_xy
Found Abc_def_ghi
Bad date: Hey_its_20182395.gif
Bad date: Foo_bar.txt
```

The pattern could simply be the following if you don't care whether the date looks at all valid:

```
private static Pattern beforeDate = Pattern.compile("([^0-9]+)_\\d{8}");
```

Comment: @user8618585 If my answer helped you, you can accept it, and upvote it when you have enough reputation.

Comment: Yeah will do that ,just got another string something like abc_xyz2_20180723_def.txt for which this is not working ,any modifications you can suggest would be really helpful .the digit 2 before the date pattern is the culprit

Comment: @user8618585 you had said numbers couldn't airway before the date. You could change the first part to `(\\w+)_`

Comment: 'Appear,' not 'airway.'

Answer (score 0):

**Try this pattern:**

```
[\w\d]+[A-Z-a-z][_]
```

You can test is [online](http://regexstorm.net/tester)

[image]